# how to save multiple columns in R as csv file?

Tags: r, machine-learning, dataset

I have a list of data frames "181", and i want to extract the 2nd column and save it in a csv file and label it, the labels for those 181 dfs are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6.
The problem is i have different length for each df, and i don't know if that's applicable in R!

Comment: Your question is unclear, so let me try out this interpretation for your reactions: you have 181 data frames identified by the numbers 0, 1, 2, and so on; and you wish to store their second columns in a CSV file in a way that identifies which data frame each value came from.  Is this correct?

Comment: i have 181 data frames each consist of 2 columns, i want to save in a csv file 2 things a label lets say y = 0 and x = 2nd column values from the data frames let's say 46,986,3974 and bind them like {y,x}, and i want to do that for the entire 181 data frames, so the first row will be: 0, 46,986,3974 and so on for the 181 rows, notice i have different length for columns for different data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an inefficient but easily coded solution (and efficiency doesn't matter when all you need to do is output a short CSV file).  It writes each data frame one line at a time, assuming the data frames are represented by a list `l.df`.

```
#
# Prepare for output and input.
#
fn <- "temp.csv"
if(is.null(names(l.df))) names(l.df) <- 1:length(l.df)
#
# Loop over the data frames.
#
append <- FALSE
for (s in names(l.df)) {
  #
  # Create a one-row data frame for this column.
  #
  X <- data.frame(ID=s, as.list(l.df[[s]][[2]]))
  #
  # Append it to the output.
  #
  write.table(X, file=fn, sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, append=append)
  append <- TRUE
}
```

For example, we may prepare a set of data frames with random entries:

```
set.seed(17)
l.df <- lapply(1+rpois(181, 5), function(n) data.frame(X=1:n, Y=round(rnorm(n),2)))
```

The output file looks like this:

```
"1",0.37,1.61,0.02,0.51
"2",1.07,0.13,-0.55,0.34,2.24,0.41,0.26,0.13,-0.48,0.07,0.54
... (177 lines omitted)
"180",0.58,-1.5,1.85,-1.02
"181",-0.59,0.12,-0.38,-0.35,1.22,-0.63,0.81
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of solving your issues, I'll just propose the simplest one with base R, looping  (otherwise work with [tidyverse](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls01_map-name-position-shortcuts.html)).
The Issue of differing df lengths (in terms of rows) can be solved by adding NAs at the end.

I assume this is your setup:

```
# Your list of data frames
yourlistofdataframes <- list()
for (i in 1:182) { # in R list indices run from 1 to 181 (in Python from 0 onwards)
  nrowofdf <- sample(1:100,1) # random number of rows between 1 and 100
  yourlistofdataframes[[i]] <- data.frame(cbind(rep(paste0("df",i,"|column1"),nrowofdf),
                                                rep(paste0("df",i,"|column2"),nrowofdf),
                                                rep(paste0("df",i,"|column3"),nrowofdf)))
}
names(yourlistofdataframes) <- 0:181 # labeling the data frames
```

Then this is your solution:

```
newlist <- list()
for (i in 1:length(yourlistofdataframes)){
  newlist[[i]] <- unlist(yourlistofdataframes[[i]][2])
}
names(newlist) <- 0:181 # give them the names you wanted
newlist <- lapply(newlist, `length<-`, max(lengths(newlist))) # add NA's to make them equal length

# bind back to data.frame & save as csv
newdf <- data.frame(newlist) # if you want to have the data in 181 columns in your final df
newdft <- t(newdf) # if you want to have the data in 181 rows in your final df
write.csv(newdf, "mycsv.csv")
```

---

**Feedback on your question**:

- *Also, if you want to ask for coding advice, post some representation of your data, so that people don't have to assume how your data looks like / build their own.*

Comment: but i have total of 181 df with un equal length, so i thought for example the first 10 are with 0 label , so the first row in the csv looks like 
label=0, Column values= 1,....,10
up till 10th row for example 
label =0, Column values = 1,...,5
i.e  1st row: 0, 980,999,989,890,720,777,809,888,999,1000
      2nd row: 0, 999,989,890,809,1000
And so on for all other labels, then I’ll end up with 181 as rows where the first element in the row is the label and the rest are the values! how can i save it in this format?

Comment: Hmm, I don't really understand your issue.
If you have a list of data frames and want to create a new data frame which has only the second column of every data frame in your list, my solution above should suffice. Else you might have to clarify a) your initial data structure and b) the data structure you want to arrive at